# go to AppStore update screen from an iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

Is there a URL I can launch from the app that will take the user to the "Updates" tab in the AppStore application on an iOS device?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to link directly to an update. I've found once an advice to replace "viewSoftware" to "viewSoftwareUpdate" on:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/139548#139548

but since link for "phobos" is no longer used it might not work any more

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one we use for our apps (where "id" is the id for your app):

```
itms-apps://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=438596432&mt=8
```

It *mostly* works. On an iPhone & iPod it goes right to the Update screen. On an iPad it goes to the store and shows an obscure error message. I filed that as a bug with Apple a few months ago.